# Codeigniter Paypal Express Checkout not passing ShippingAMT and TAXAMT

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, e-commerce, express-checkout

Here is the problem - I am using Codeigniter as my framework and integrating Paypal Express Checkout. The library that I am using is the CI_MERCHANT and it works quite fine however when I print_r the parameters sending in and then asking a GetTransactionDetails back they are different

Here is what i am sending over:

```
    Array
(
    [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
    [VERSION] => 94.0
    [USER] => ***
    [PWD] => ***
    [SIGNATURE] => ***
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Authorization
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 37.95
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 35.95
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC] => invoice-#test
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 1.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 1.00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Item_1
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => 
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 35.95
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
    [AMT] => 37.95
    [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Sole
    [LANDINGPAGE] => Billing
    [ALLOWNOTE] => 1
    [RETURNURL] => URL/ACCEPT
    [CANCELURL] => URL/DECLINE
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] => first_name second_name
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => address1
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2] => address2
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => city
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => state
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => zip
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM] => 
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_EMAIL] => email@dot.com
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM] => 1468808
    [upload] => 1
)
```

The Response I get is:

```
Array
(
    [RECEIVEREMAIL] => ***
    [RECEIVERID] => ***
    [EMAIL] => email@dot.com
    [PAYERID] => ***
    [PAYERSTATUS] => verified
    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
    [SHIPTONAME] => first_name last_name
    [SHIPTOSTREET] => address1
    [SHIPTOCITY] => city
    [SHIPTOSTATE] => state
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United States
    [SHIPTOZIP] => ZIP
    [ADDRESSOWNER] => PayPal
    [ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
    [INVNUM] => 1468808
    [SALESTAX] => 0.00
    [SUBJECT] => invoice-#test
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-07-03T01:29:04Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => b64ae0d8c4388
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 94.0
    [BUILD] => 6561328
    [FIRSTNAME] => first_name
    [LASTNAME] => last_name
    [TRANSACTIONID] => ***
    [TRANSACTIONTYPE] => cart
    [PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
    [ORDERTIME] => 2013-07-03T01:29:02Z
    [AMT] => 35.95
    [TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
    [PENDINGREASON] => paymentreview
    [REASONCODE] => None
    [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Ineligible
    [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => None
    [L_NAME0] => Item_1
    [L_QTY0] => 1
    [L_TAXAMT0] => 0.00
    [L_SHIPPINGAMT0] => 0.00
    [L_HANDLINGAMT0] => 0.00
    [L_CURRENCYCODE0] => USD
    [L_TAXABLE0] => false
    [L_AMT0] => 35.95
}
```

I have tried the following:
using different version declaration.
I know that SHIPPINGAMT and TAXAMT have been deprecated since version 63.0 so i have tried to use it and set it to version 61 to no avail.

Also inside the sandbox account the "client" is only charged the ITEMAMT and not the full amount with the shipping. However during checkout it does pass the amount as the total being displayed is the ITEMAMT + SHIPPING + TAX.

anyone got a n idea what is going on?

Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're calling GetExpressCheckoutDetails prior to calling DoExpressCheckoutPayment..??

I'm pretty sure what you're seeing is the expected result.  Until DoExpressCheckoutPayment is called the shipping and tax amounts could change, so GECD wouldn't reflect anything yet.

When you redirect to PayPal are you seeing the shipping and tax included in the order review?  If so then you're doing everything correctly.  It's just that, again, GECD doesn't include those details since they could change.  For example, you could call GECD to obtain the payer's shipping address so that you could then calculate shipping and tax accordingly, and that could be different than what you sent with SEC.

Anyway, check that you're able to see what you send in SEC in the review pages at PayPal, and then finalize everything with DECP and I'm guessing you'll see that it gets included as expected (so long as you include it the same way in your DECP request.)

Comment: Hi - I do not use GetExpressCheckoutDetails - im sending everything directly to the paypal redirect. (which is what i showed in the first array). During that time the shipping and taxes are shown to the user however afterwards the capture is of the incorrect amount with missing shipping and tax amount.

Comment: So what about your DoExpressCheckoutPayment request?  You need to make sure the shipping and tax are included in that too.

Comment: I never called it - i do the set to get the token, then i send over the parameters with the redirect, the sandbox pays, and returns to the url specify. which what both arrays shows. Am i missing a flow?

Comment: You can't complete the process without DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  If you're not calling that then the money is not actually being moved.  After you're redirected back to your site is when you make that call to finalize everything.

Comment: But the Payment IS moved - just missing the shipping and taxes. Like as a test merchant - I CAN capture the payment just short. If this aint correct - then what is the correct flow to achieve this: My Site Shipping Information + Email -> Paypal Website Redirect Showing customer items and final total -> Paypal redirects to my ACCEPTED page with the customer's information with the proper captured amount with shipping

Comment: If the payment is indeed being moved then you have to be calling DECP at some point.  The flow for Express Checkout is SEC, GECD (optional), and DECP to finalize it.  Without DECP it won't process.  Simple as that, so if you're seeing the transaction show up in the seller account then you must be calling it.  As such, you just need to make sure the shipping and tax values are filled into your DECP request the same they are in the SEC request so that they'll be included in the finalized payment.

Comment: Hi - I have finally found DECP - so from what you are saying - despite sending shipping/tax in SEC - I need to do the same within DECP in order to get the full capture?

Comment: So are you seeing everything like you expect now?

Comment: Yes - I was initially only passing the token back to the authorized_return which had the DECP - in turn once i dug deep it was actually recreating the entire SEC and was missing the shipping parameter